# any way to search a user answers by tag

Tags: support, search

I want to search in the specific user profile in his/her answers parts by clarify  a tag ? Is there any way? Like search for all answers which have a network tag from specific user.So is there any way?

Comment: oops.Oh found that so easy just by clicking on that user tags. shame :(

Comment: 5 hours later....seems become a good questions :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advanced search options provide a fairly simple method:

```
user:449 [command-line] is:a
```

That should show you my posts, in the command line tag, that are answers.

If searching your own, you can use `user:me`.

Comment: Furthermore, if you go to the user's profile page, the `user:XXX` bit is filled in for you in the search field.